# Распарсивание string полей в json-е на golang выводится с кавычками

Tags: golang

Клиент отправляет json такого типа

```
{"function":"GroupAdd","data":"Имя новой группы"}
```

Распарсиваю json

```
   type struct_json struct { 
      Function string
      Data     json.RawMessage  
   }

    ...
    var Struct_json = &struct_json{} 
    var b_clientMessage =[]byte(clientMessage)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b_clientMessage, Struct_json) 
    if err != nil {
       log.Println("error:", err)
    }

    switch Struct_json.Function {
    case "GroupAdd":
       GroupAdd(Id,string(Struct_json.Data))
    ...
    func GroupAdd(UserId int, Name string){
        query := "insert into groups(Name,UserId) values (?,?)"
        if new_query_exec(query, Name, UserId){ //тут записывается в БД
            Refresh_Groups()    
        }
    }
```

В итоге я хочу, что б в БД добавилась группа- Имя новой группы , а получаю это же значение в кавычках.
Как избавиться от кавычек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `interface{}` вместо `json.RawMessage`, тогда если в поле `data` будет строка, она прочитается как `string`.

```
type struct_json struct {
    Function string
    Data     interface{}
}

text := []byte(`{"function":"GroupAdd","data":"Имя новой группы"}`)
parsed := &struct_json{}
json.Unmarshal(text, parsed)

data, _ := parsed.Data.(string)
fmt.Println(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct_json.Data` у вас типа `json.RawMessage`. Этот тип надо дальше декодировать в другие структуры, он не предназначен для использования как есть:

```
switch Struct_json.Function {
    case "GroupAdd":
        var id string
        err := json.Unmarshal(Struct_json.Data, &id)
        // Проверка err.
        GroupAdd(ID, id)
```